# Prevent Powershell from truncating output

Tags: powershell

Trying to figure out which file errored out, but `...hamburg (3).jpg` isn't very descriptive.
Considering I got dozens of these errors, I have essentially no way of knowing what went wrong.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At O:\projects\scripts\restrict_name.ps1:66 char:7
+   } | Rename-Item -NewName {
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\usr\Do...hamburg (3).jpg:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Why does Powershell allocate so little space to paths even their own path portion (C:\Users\usr\Do**wnloads**) is truncated - let alone any additional user directories - and is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: This is just _formatted_ error output, the underlying data is still there. `$Error |Where-Object FullyQualifiedErrorId -Like RenameItemIOError* |ForEach-Object TargetObject`

Comment: Where do I put that code?

Comment: You put it at whichever point you want to print the names of all the files that, at that point, couldn't be renamed because the new name already existed - at the end of the script for example? It's impossible for me to say because you haven't posted the actual code you're running :-)